# How to log into IBM Bluemix using REST API?

Tags: go, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am trying to use the Cloud Foundry [go-cfclient](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/go-cfclient) to work with IBM Bluemix and the REST API in Go. I already fail with the login process. I am using the following sample code and invoke the program by passing in the Bluemix endpoint "https://api.ng.bluemix.net" and my userid/password info.

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "os"

    cfclient "github.com/cloudfoundry-community/go-cfclient"
)

func main() {
    api := flag.String("api", "", "API endpoint")
    username := flag.String("username", "", "User name")
    password := flag.String("password", "", "password")
    help := flag.Bool("help", false, "help")

    flag.Parse()

    if *help || len(*api) == 0 || len(*username) == 0 || len(*password) == 0 {
        flag.Usage()
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    config := &cfclient.Config{
        ApiAddress: *api,
        Username:   *username,
        Password:   *password}

    fmt.Println("user %v\n",*username)
    var (
        client *cfclient.Client
        err    error
    )

    if client, err = cfclient.NewClient(config); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(client)

    apps, err := client.ListApps()

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(apps)
}
```

The error returned is:

> panic: Error getting token: oauth2: cannot fetch token: 401
>   Unauthorized Response:
>   {"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"Bad credentials"}

What information needs to be provided? How can I log into Bluemix using the REST API?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the go library, but it looks like it accepts a Password attribute.  Maybe that should be used instead of Token?

Comment: Sorry, it is `Password`, not the token. I had experimented with both to see whether the oauth token could be passed in. I corrected the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is an example](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bluemix-generator/blob/master/modules/bluemix-api-client.js#L34) of logging into Bluemix using the REST API (in JavaScript).

You make a call to the login endpoint and request a token with your username and password from Bluemix.

[image: body of request]

[image: headers of request]

Comment: Assuming that the example works, it will help to understand the flow. I am also looking into trace. However, the real problem would be how to use the `go-cfclient` library.

Comment: Well, from looking at this library, it looks like it's trying to get the token from `https://uaa.ng.bluemix.net/oauth/token` rather than `https://login.ng.bluemix.net/UAALoginServerWAR/oauth/token` which is the reason why it's failing authentication.

Comment: Yup. That's what I also found out so far. See here https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/go-cfclient/issues/32 The question is now why it is using that URI